# how to replace my project with a .git folder

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, gitlab

I am completely new to Git.

I am working on an eclipse project that uses GitLab. I would like to replace the current project I am using with one of the branches on the GitLab server.

I downloaded the repository as .git folder. Now I am wonder how I can completely change my current project with that .git project. Or if there any other way to do it with commands it would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout another branch using Git (either on command line or using some Git plugin for Eclipse), not by downloading anything.

```
git checkout another_branch_name
```

Comment: Thank you but where do I do it? I have my project under workspace, and I go to the commandline to the project and when I run the command it says: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories) . git

Comment: you haven't checked the project out from git then ( see git clone)